# How the accessbility of a class or function in C++ is controlled

Tags: c++, public

In language like C#. you can put public or internal in front of a class to control the access level of a class. How this is done in an C++ DLL?

Comment: It's all about header files.

Comment: do you mean if the user includes a header file, together with a static library or DLL, he will always be able to access a class.

Comment: Outer classes are all implicitly public (for inner classes see Bar Siete's answer).

Comment: For C++ dll's things are a lot more complicated.  Effectively, everything is internal by default, unless you use a special compiler flag to mark it as needing to be "exported".  The header used by the exe will also need to know that the things in the header must be "imported" from a dll.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're basically asking how to export a class from a DLL.

In that case, most compilers for Windows (e.g., VC++, MinGW) use `__declspec(dllexport)` to do the job.

To mirror that, the client codes need to declare the class as `__declspec(dllimport)`. Typically you end up with something like:

```
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL class whatever { 
    // ...
};
```

...in the header, then the make file for building the DLL will define `BUILD_DLL`:

```
cflags += /DBUILD_DLL
```

Answer (score 0):

By nesting one class inside another:

```
class A
{
public:
    class B {};
protected:
    class C {};
private:
    class D {};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C#(or any other modern languages) C++ language standard doesn't talks anything about Dynamic Libraries/Shared Objects.

So it is all specific to the language/compiler implementors to define their own way of exporting class definitions across DLL/SO.

Refer http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility for more info.

```
#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
  #ifdef BUILDING_DLL
    #ifdef __GNUC__
      #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllexport))
    #else
      #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllexport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
    #endif
  #else
    #ifdef __GNUC__
      #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((dllimport))
    #else
      #define DLL_PUBLIC __declspec(dllimport) // Note: actually gcc seems to also supports this syntax.
    #endif
  #endif
  #define DLL_LOCAL
#else
  #if __GNUC__ >= 4
    #define DLL_PUBLIC __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
    #define DLL_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
  #else
    #define DLL_PUBLIC
    #define DLL_LOCAL
  #endif
#endif

extern "C" DLL_PUBLIC void function(int a);
class DLL_PUBLIC SomeClass
{
   int c;
   DLL_LOCAL void privateMethod();  // Only for use within this DSO
public:
   Person(int _c) : c(_c) { }
   static void foo(int a);
};
```

From the above snippet you can observe that exporting class is directly dependent on the compiler specific extension.

```
CL/MSVC - __declspec(dllexport), __declspec(dllimport
GCC - __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
```

GCC also provide **-fvisibility=[hidden|default] to have a more control over the symbols which is been exported over DLL/SO.